# The homology groups of an infinite product of spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, product-space

Suppose $I$ is some index set and let $\{X_i \}_{i\in I}$ be a collection of topological spaces (as nice as you like them to be). What is known about the (say) singular homology of $X := \prod_{i\in I} X_i$?

If $I$ is finite, there are of course Künneth formulas that relate $H_*(X_i)$ to $H_*(X)$. I am looking for similar tools to compute $H_*(X)$ in the case that the index set is infinite. I am not looking for the most general statement one might make, so please assume additional hypotheses if they are needed.

Comment: I guess this is asking about the infinite product with the product topology, in which case $X$ will often not be locally contractible at any it's points. Standard methods won't apply here and I think this is an open problem.  In fact, I doubt the groups $H_n((S^1)^{\mathbb{N}})$ (the homology groups of the infinite dimensional torus) have been characterized for $n\geq 2$. There are copies of $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ in $H_n((S^1)^{\mathbb{N}})$ in every dimension $n\geq 1$, so all of these groups will be uncountable.

Comment: @JeremyBrazas -- I didn't know you were on MSE! I'm a big fan of your blog. I'm a logician who likes algebraic topology, so I was immediately interested when I learned about Katsuya Eda's work applying descriptive set theory to wild algebraic topology. Some googling pretty quickly brought me to your blog and I've been reading it ever since ^_^.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thanks! This is a neat question that I have wondered about before. In fact, this is probably worth adding to my problem list.